# Error[e46]: Undefined external "set_all_ports" referred in GPIO main

Tags: c

I want to create my own driver which consists of one .c file and one .h file.
The .c file is:

```
#include <msp430f5438a.h>
#include "ports_init.h"

extern void set_all_ports(unsigned char direction, unsigned char state)
{
   P1DIR = direction;
   P2DIR = direction;
   P3DIR = direction;
   P4DIR = direction;
   P5DIR = direction;
   P6DIR = direction;
   P7DIR = direction;
   P8DIR = direction;
   P9DIR = direction;
   P10DIR = direction;
   P11DIR = direction;
   PJDIR = direction; 

   P1OUT = state;
   P2OUT = state;
   P3OUT = state;
   P4OUT = state;
   P5OUT = state;
   P6OUT = state;
   P7OUT = state;
   P8OUT = state;
   P9OUT = state;
   P10OUT = state;
   P11OUT = state;
   PJOUT = state;
}
```

The .h file is:

```
#ifndef _PORTS_INIT_
#define _PORTS_INIT_

//Function prototypes
void set_all_ports(unsigned char direction, unsigned char state);

#define HIGH_STATE   0xFFu
#define LOW_STATE    0x00u

#define OUTPUTS      0xFFu
#define INPUTS       0x00u

#endif
```

And the my code is:

```
#include <msp430f5438a.h>
#include "ports_init.h"
int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop watchdog timer
  P4DIR |= 0x03;                            // Set P2.0 to output direction
  P4OUT = 0x00;

  P1DIR &= ~BIT7;
  P1REN = BIT7;
  P1OUT = BIT7;  
  set_all_ports(OUTPUTS, LOW_STATE);
  while (1)                                 
     ;
}
```

Unfortunately when I compile my source code I get the error: 
 Error[e46]: Undefined external "set_all_ports" referred in GPIO main. My question is how to modify my .c and .h files in order to make this error to disappear. I know it is a not a good practice to include the .c file into my source code. That's why I want to call the functions that reside in ports_init.c by including only ports_init.h in my source code, like it happens in the real APIs. I am using IAR embedded workbench for MSP430. Excuse my bad English, I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is that in your .c file you declare the function as extern void, I think it should be just void